# Tables with clustered indexes or heap tables?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

What if I have table `X` (heap table) that is being frequently updated (`INSERT` and `DELETE` only), and table `Y` which can never exceed 2000 rows. Table `X` has a foreign key column that references a unique index of table `Y`, and the relationship type is one-to-many. However there can only be maximum of 10 foreign keys per unique index, which means that table `X` can never exceed 20000 rows. Basically table `X` can have any amount of rows between 0-20000 at any moment. Makes sense?

So is heap table good there or should I add a clustered index there? Or maybe someone has an even better solution?

Comment: The number of rows is really small, and you can't explicitly add clustered indexes using MySQL so in general it shouldn't matter really seeing the dataset is small. To my knowledge, only engines that support it are InnoDB (which clusters by primary key only) and TokuDB so I don't know how you plan on adding clustered indexes. Did you mean covering indexes maybe?

Comment: I haven't created any tables yet, I'm just wondering whether it's better to create a heap table (without primary key) or a table with clustered index (with primary key) for such operation.

Comment: Personally, I can't think of a case why you wouldn't want to have a primary key. If you don't create one, InnoDB will create an internal one (which is 8-byte integer instead of the "usual" 4-byte one that all of us are used to using). Also, InnoDB clusters using this PK so.. what exactly would you lose here? I'm mentioning InnoDB because it's standard MySQL engine, I've no idea if you're using something else or not. In the end, you have only 20k records, if you're worried about performance - I'd get a better hard drive before tampering with proved design principles.

Comment: Okay thanks, I agree that every table should generally have a clustered index, but in this case the table may have 100 rows and the next moment it may have just 20 rows etc. I thought that this might be one of those rare cases where heap table is better.

Comment: Considering you'll perform inserts and deletes much quicker if you use PK instead of any other index, I personally think this particular case isn't one of those special cases :)